# Unable to send data from rails app in aws to android app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passenger

I have built a rails app which interacts with an android application. Sending and receiving data from android on localhost is working flawlessly. But when I upload to an AWS EC2 instance, I'm only able to send data from android to server not the other way around.

I am using passenger gem to upload in AWS.

My rails code to accept request from app which gives 200 OK

```
class Android::OnetimeloginController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
# This handles one time login from the android app

  def create

    # Takes up the credentials from the android app and
    # sends the header token to be used for further pings
        credentials = permitted_credentials

    # Checks the credentials and renders the responses 
      if credentials.has_key?("name")
        if Branch.exists?(name: credentials["something"]) && credentials["password"] == "something"

          response_json =  {"response" => "Yes"}
            render :json => response_json
        else
          render :text => "NO"
        end

      end

  end

  private

  def permitted_credentials
    params.require("credentials").permit(:name, :password, :tablet_id)
  end
end
```

But I'm not getting anything on the android side(although I get response in localhost)

I even got response for my CURL request.
My curl command.

```
 curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"credentials":{"name" : "something", "password": "something"}}'  http://IP/path_to_controller
```

I checked putting "Content-type" and "Accept" headers from android request, but no use.

Please tell me where am I going wrong? Is it an AWS problem?

Comment: Are you making a request from a page in the mobile web browser? If so, from where does the web page get served?

Comment: @Emil I'm a making a request from an android app using volley and nothing  is being responded

Comment: Do you see your request and response in the server logs ?

Comment: Yes Emil I'm getting request from android and response is 200 OK from rails server.

Comment: So you're able to get the response from EC2 using curl on localhost, but the same request doesn't give you any response on the mobile. That's tricky. I've no clue, but I'll recommend using a debugger to see what's going on after you make the request using the HTTP client in the mobile.

Comment: thanks emil...the problem was with volley...didn't expect at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same bug. Its not a problem with your rails script. I think that the volley framework that you have used might have been corrupt or buggy. Try importing the library from any other source using gradle. Try importing from mcxiaoke.volley. It worked for me....

Comment: thanks Nikhil Gopinath...I didn't think that the problem will be with the volley. worked like charm